# Confirming existence in polynomial time while solution finding is NP-complete

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity

Assume P≠NP.

Say there's an NP-complete decision problem:

> Does $P$ have a $Q$ ?

And we have a proposition $F$ computable in polynomial time, where $F(P)$ implies the existence of a solution in the original problem.

My question is:

> Is there a "natural" case such that finding $Q$ is non-polynomial (maybe NP-hard?) even if $F(P)$ is given?

Insight:

Many theorems concerning the existence of a solution of a NP-complete problem is just a polynomial-time algorithm, e.g. Chvatal-Erdos theorem, Ore's condition, Kőnig's theorem on edge-coloring bipartite graphs. I wonder whether all such theorems should be of this kind.

Of course there are counterexamples.

Let $P$ be a bunch of statements, and the decision problem is "Does $P$ have a true statement ?", and $F$ searches for statements with the form $A$ and $¬A$. Surely, $F(P)$ implies the existence of a true statement, but picking out the statement is definitely hard. However, it seems too unnatural.

This  [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c140/ed07036e8653f0f6f0b38c530a84a6d0e20b.pdf) provides an example about finding Hamilton cycles:$|d − λ_i
| ≤ c \frac{(log log n)^2}{log n(log log log n)}d$ implies Hamiltonicity, and they provide an algorithm of $n^{
clnn}$ time. I'm not sure whether there is a polynomial-time algorithm or not. If there's no such algorithm, finding Hamiltonian cycles in those graphs constitutes a case.